# CMake set environment variable

Tags: linux, cmake, environment-variables

According to the CMake documentation

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/set.html

One can do

```
set(ENV{<variable>} <value>)
```

but this gives the result

```
set(ENV{FOO} foo)
message("variable is $ENV{FOO}")
```

at configure time

```
variable is foo
```

But at Linux command

```
echo $FOO
```

the variable is not set.

EDIT:

Here's a partial solution to the problem, which was to set `$PATH`, so that a user has `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` listed first

```
set(file_sh ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/path.sh)
set(path "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}:$ENV{PATH}")
file(WRITE ${file_sh} "#!/usr/bin/env bash\n")
file(APPEND ${file_sh} "export PATH=\"${path}\"")
execute_process(COMMAND chmod a+x ${file_sh} RESULT_VARIABLE res)
```

this creates this file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH="/install/prefix/path:/other/path"
```

that later can be executed on a bash terminal with

```
source path.sh
```

Comment: Where do you call `echo $FOO`?

Comment: @arrowd 'echo $FOO' is at linux bash

Comment: After running `cmake`? You can't change parent (bash) environment from a child process.

Answer (score -3):

The last paragraph of the documentation you cited gives the answer:

`Set the current process environment <variable> to the given value.`

It influences the current process environment that is created when CMake is started from the shell. It is not the environment of the shell itself.

Comment: ok , but the paragraph title says **Set Environment Variable** The Cmake documentation is not the best I've found

Comment: I understand your complains about the documentation, but how the environment is provided to the process is operation system specific and similar in Unix/Linux and Windows. Every process (e.g. your bash) that creates a child process (your cmake) provides the newly process a copy of its environment. You cannot change the environment of the parent process later. But you can start a intermediate process that sets the environment variables and then starts cmake.